# Linux command line remove files recursively which dont exist in other folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I have the following folder structure in folder /1:

```
/1/1/
  1.png
  2.png
  5.png
  6.png

/1/2/
  3.png
  4.png

/1/3/
  10.png
  11.png
  14.png
```

there are subfolders 1-3 in this example. in real live its hundreds of folders. each subfolder contains an unknown amount of png files in it.

then i have a folder /2 which has the exact same subfolder structure but more images in it then folder /1:

```
/2/1/
  1.jpg
  2.jpg
  3.jpg
  4.jpg
  5.jpg
  5.jpg

/2/2/
  1.jpg
  2.jpg
  3.jpg
  4.jpg

/2/3/
  10.jpg
  11.jpg
  12.jog
  13.jpg
  14.jpg
```

Please note that different file extension in folder 2 (.jpg). What the files have in common is only the file name. the extension is different in folders /1 and /2.

What i try to achieve in Linux is to clean folder /2 and have there only the images which exist a file in folder /1 with the same name.

Can anybody provide me with a command i can use from the command line or a bash script?

The final result in folder /2 should be:

```
/2/1/
  1.jpg
  2.jpg
  5.jpg
  6.jpg

/2/2/
  3.jpg
  4.jpg

/2/3/
  10.jpg
  11.jpg
  14.jpg
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do this with `find` and a simple `while` loop in bash:

```
cd /path/to/2 || exit 1
find -type f -name '*.jpg' -print0 |
    while IFS= read -r -d '' path; do
        if [[ ! -e "/path/to/1/${path%.jpg}.png" ]]; then
                  # ^^^^^^^^^^ adjust this path
            echo rm -- "$path"
           #^^^^ remove this after the first dry-run
        fi
    done
```

Run it once to echo if it would remove the correct files, and if everything looks ok, run it again having removed the `echo` from `rm`.

Comment: I suggest to append `|| exit 1` to `cd /path/to/2`.

Comment: @redneb thank you - looks like exactly what I need. However I get: line 3: -r: command not found

Comment: @domi771 Oops, my bad. I had misplaced the `read`. I fixed it now.

Comment: Instead of commenting "adjust this path" deeply embedded in the code, perhaps add `DIR1=${1?} DIR2=${2?}` at the top (if in a script), or in the code write `cd "${DIR2?}"; .. if [[ -e "${DIR1?}${path%.jpg}.png"...`